# "Variable weights already exists" in RNN sample code from tutorial

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I want re-implement RNN step loop from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/static_rnn
but it doesn't work for me.
I get "Variable test/basic_lstm_cell/weights already exists" without reuse and "Variable test/basic_lstm_cell/weights does not exist" when reuse is set to True.

```
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 32
n_steps = 10
lstm_size = 10
n_input = 17

words = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, n_steps, n_input])
words = tf.transpose(words, [1, 0, 2])
words = tf.reshape(words, [-1, n_input])
words = tf.split(words, n_steps, 0)

with tf.variable_scope('test', reuse=True):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
    state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
    outputs = []
    for input_ in words:
        output, state = cell(input_, state)
        outputs.append(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [the source of the function you are trying to re-implement](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/0e226af/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/core_rnn.py#L182). The important bit is that the reuse flag is not set in the first iteration of the loop, but it is set in all others. So in your case one scope which contains the loop with the flag constant for the scope won't work, you'll have to do something like

```
with tf.variable_scope('test') as scope:
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size)
    state = cell.zero_state(batch_size, dtype=tf.float32)
    outputs = []
    for step, input_ in enumerate(words):
        if step > 0:
            scope.reuse_variables()
        output, state = cell(input_, state)
        outputs.append(output)
```